# Calculating upper and lower bounds of the probability of outcome i occuring?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

Let's say we observe a sample choosing between three possible outcomes: a, b, and c. We can then easily calculate the probability of an individual choosing outcome a: # people choosing a / total # number of people making a choice.

How can we then add an estimate of the upper and lower bounds of the probability of a occurring?

EDIT: I suppose I could use a bootstrapping procedure: sample from the population (with replacement), make this probability calculation, repeat ~5,000 times, and then measure the 2.5% and 97.5% percentiles to derive a confidence interval on the probabilities. However, perhaps there is a simpler answer out there. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `prop.test` function in R seems like it would be appropriate. It will take a proportion (e.g. 20 a values drawn from 30 total draws) and calculate the confidence interval around that proportion with the following code:

```
prop.test(20, 30, correct = FALSE)
```

Which gives a 95% confidence interval of 48.7% to 80.7% (around a sample value of 66.6%).

Comment: Thank you: prop.test is just the sort of thing I was looking for. Unfortunately, I lack the "reputation" to provide up votes, but I would if I could.

Comment: By the way, do you have any intuition on when to apply Yates' continuity correction? In other words, why did you mark it as false in the example above?

Comment: Just reading through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates's_correction_for_continuity, it seems that it's an overly conservative correction. But also I noticed that if the correction is set to true, the resulting confidence interval changes slightly depending on the parameter p, which you're not interested in and so seems undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a plain multinomial problem.

If you are interested only in a confidence interval on each outcome on its own, you can think of all other categories as "not-$i$", reducing it to plain binomial sampling.

There's a lot of material on [binomial proportion confidence intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

As such, packages offer CIs for these proportions as a matter of course. Both large and small samples are regularly done.

If you're doing it by hand, the approach of "add 2 to the successes and failures" combined with the usual large-sample interval (i.e. the Agresti-Coull approach at the link above) works surprisingly well even at fairly small sample sizes.

Comment: Thanks - this is very helpful for the general intuition of the problem.